# undefined method `round' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i followed a video tutorial on How To Build A Movie Review App with Rails 4.

and i found this problem,
when i write a review without rating this problem happens

[image]

movies_controller.rb

```
   def show
    @reviews = Review.where(movie_id: @movie.id).order("created_at DESC")

    if @reviews.blank?
     @avg_review = 0
       else
       @avg_review = @movie.reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
    end
end
```

i tried to do this but it seems that it's not working to

```
  def show
    @reviews = Review.where(movie_id: @movie.id).order("created_at DESC")

    if @reviews.blank?
     @avg_review = 0
      elsif !@reviews.blank? && @movie.rating.blank?
        @avg_review = 0
       else
       @avg_review = @movie.reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
    end
  end
```

please is there in solution for this problem

Comment: @movie.reviews.average(:rating) is null b/c avg rating is nil. Please make sure the rating exists for the movie.

Comment: yep when i write a review without rating there's nothing to divide by 2 that's why the problem happens

Comment: `if i write a review without rating that's mean that
!@reviews.blank? = true
@movie.rating.blank? = true
it should assign @avg_review = 0 and stop there why it continues and assign
@avg_review = @movie.reviews.average(:rating).round(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
def show
    @reviews =  @movie.reviews.order("created_at DESC")
    unless @reviews.present?
     @avg_review = 0
    else
     @avg_review = @reviews.average(:rating).present? ? @reviews.average(:rating).round(2) : 0
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks for help it works great now but please can you simplify this condition               @avg_review = @reviews.average(:rating).present? ? @reviews.average(:rating).round(2) : 0

Comment: ya sure, its ternary condition when first statement is true then its run immediate statement after  ? and if condition false its run statement after ':'